# Nhibernate Loquacious Mapping By Code (Not-Found=Ignore)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am trying to create a ManyToOne map over a legacy database, as such need it to ignore any orphaned records.

The original xml way of describing it was:

```xml
<many-to-one not-found="ignore" />
```

But I am unable to describe it using NHibernate 3.2 Mapping by Code.

The code I am using to describe the map is below:

```cs
ManyToOne(x => x.Gang, manyToOne =>
        {
            manyToOne.Column("gang_code");
            manyToOne.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            manyToOne.NotNullable(true);
        });
```

The NotNullable(true) is there since there should always be a gang for a new or updated record, but need the record to be read/selected to allow users to change it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not yet supported. You can enter an issue at https://nhibernate.jira.com.

In the meantime, keep using XML to map that class.

You can also clone https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core and patch `(I)ManyToOneMapper`

---

Edit: I implemented it in my fork. I'm too lazy to create the test, Jira and pull request now, but you can use it as-is.

Edit: this is now implemented in the trunk; it will be available in the next release.

Comment: Logged an issue as suggested [Link to Issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2992).

Many thanks for the code, will help until the issue has been sorted.